# Why was it nessesury to allow std::move accept reference to lvalue besides reference to rvalue in Uref embodiment for both?

Tags: c++, move, rvalue, lvalue

Considering that rvalue-ness and lvalue-ness are not a features of objects but of expressions.

Why isn't `std::move` implemented only for lvalue reference argument, but for universal one? Whereas it is useful only for retrieving rvalue reference from an lvalue? When rvalue is rvalue already and it does not need `std::move` functionality.

```
template <typename T>
typename std::remove_reference_t<T>&& move(T&& x)
{
  return static_cast<std::remove_reference_t<T>&&>(x);
}
```

Comment: Not quite clear what you are asking.  Note that `std::move` does not generate any code and rvalue to rvalue is a no-op at compile time.  This makes templated code much easier to write.

Comment: What if you are writing templated code that could be dealing with either RValues or LValues?

Comment: @Frank I suspect that it's the reason - to handle such a situations

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Why isn't std::move implemented only for lvalue reference argument, but for universal one?

Because lvalue references to non-const cannot be bound to xvalues.

> When rvalue is rvalue already and it does not need std::move functionality.

We want `std::move(some_expression)` to work whether `some_expression` is an rvalue expression or lvalue expression. That is particularly important in templates where that detail can depend on template arguments and we don't want to write separate specialisations for each.

Basically same reason as why these are allowed:

```
using T = const U;
const T var;

using S = T&;
S& ref = var;
```

In this case, we want to be able to declare `const T var`, and `S&` whether the types are already const/reference or not.